# Upgrading a conda environment.yml file to current version that supports pandas 1.4.1

Tags: python, pandas, visual-studio-code, conda, environment

I have a `environment.yml` file and need pandas 1.4.1 and NOT pandas 1.4.2 due to a regression. How do I upgrade the active environment to everything that is current with pandas 1.4.1 without doing it one by one. Like I cannot run Python 3.10.x because pandas 1.4.1 last compatible with python 3.9.12. Is there a way to do this in the prompt?

**Edit:**

So my .yml file has 30 or so packages but I cannot go to the current package of pandas at 1.4.2 but instead to only 1.4.1. All the other packages are old too, like python=3.8.1 in the .yml. What I need is for every package to go as updated as they can while maintaining pandas=1.4.1. Is that easy to do without going dependecy conflict chekcing of each package?

Comment: Why not make a new environment?

Comment: I am but how do I match the code for everything already in my app? I have lots of import statements.

Comment: That only makes me more confused. Please add details to the question. Right now it says you have a YAML file - which under typical circumstances one would simply edit the `pandas` line to `pandas=1.4.1` and update the environment with `conda env update`.

Comment: so if pandas in YML is set at 1.4.1 and python=3.8.x and I run conda env update doesn't everything go up? Or should I just create a YML with pandas by itself and do conda env update to get everything else I need? I am a .net programmer recently doing python.

Comment: Consider adding the YAML to the body of the question to get more precise advice.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't update in place, but instead create a new environment starting from a minimal YAML from the previous environment. This gives you the freedom to make mistakes and simply create new environments until you get it right.<sup>**1**</sup>

Namely, dump out the old environment with:

```bash
conda env export --from-history > environment.min.yaml
```

Edit this YAML to have the versions you wish to specify, like

**environment.min.yaml**

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - pandas=1.4.1
# ...
```

Then create a new environment with that,

```bash
conda env create -n my_new_env -f environment.min.yaml
```

---

<sub>**[1]** Personally, I think the biggest beginner mistake is not being liberal enough with creating environments. Same goes with branches in git. Once a developer realizes they can freely create new versions without breaking old ones, it offers a much less risk-prone playground in which to experiment.</sub>

Comment: Yes I have like 10 env i am playing with a double yes on git as I do that all the time with a good naming convention

Comment: Also, minor note, but it is usually easier solving-wise to specific Python up through minor version. Otherwise, the solution space can get a bit unwieldy.

Comment: I was starting with this: `dependencies:
  - python=3.9.12=h6244533_0
  - pandas=1.4.1=py38hd77b12b_1`

Comment: In using the above method, I now have to do what I didn't want to do, when I run my python code it can't find all the imports, like it doesn't know where flask is. I was hoping to do like conda update to get everything as high as I could to pandas=1.4.1 but that isn't seem to work ot.

Comment: @cdub that shows build strings (e.g., `py38hd77b12b_1`), which shouldn't normally be included with `conda env export --from-history`. Adding the full YAML to the question would help give a more precise recommendation.

Comment: That is true, but even removing that and using the yaml you attached for only pandas 1.4.1 and python3.9 and then creating the environment will create the environment, but the second I run the app, it looks for other packages. Is there any tool that will take the 2 packages in the yaml you have, and then build outh the env for me based on all my imports and dependencies?